# Close callback or WM_CLOSE from a HWND reference

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wndproc, hwnd

I'm calling the HtmlHelpA winapi method to display the .chm of my app. This method returns a HWND immediatelly, and the help window is shown as a separate window.

Along with the window, I set a timer for this hwnd. My problem is that I need to know when this window gets closed to kill the timer.

My first approach was trying to register the WndProc callback, but I couldn't do that because I'm not creating the window, I only have a reference to the hwnd.

Then I tried with a hook (SetWindowsHookEx) but the HOOKPROC won't bring the HWND as a parameter to the callback. Besides, I need to know the thread for this hwnd.

Is there any way to register a callback when a HWND gets closed or having a WndProc to wait for the WM_CLOSE message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to subclass the help window.  Subclassing gives you a chance to spy on all the messages going to the window proc.  You do whatever additional work you need when you see a message of interest, and then pass the message on to the original window procedure for normal processing.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

WNDPROC fnOldProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(::SetWindowLongPtr(hwndHelp, GWLP_WNDPROC, &MyWndProc));


LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    if (msg == WM_CLOSE) {
        // Kill your timer here.
    }
    return CallWindowProc(fnOldProc, hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did to keep the existing WindowProc being called.

Comment: I see from Rob's comment that the window is owned by another process, so subclassing won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If required you can register a new window procedure for an existing window.  Check out the documentation on [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Invoking it like this:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, &MyCustomHelpWindowProc);
```

Just remember that window subclassing is very delicate.  You might want to store the old window procedure somewhere and invoke that rather than `DefWindowProc()` for messages you are not interested in.

Comment: It's not that easy. The window you're modifying belongs to the hh.exe process, not your own, so the code address you store for that window won't be valid.

Comment: Thanks! Using a global map to hold the old WndProc for each hwnd I've been able to call the former WndProc from My_WndProc that checks the WM_CLOSE in a sort of "inheritance"

Comment: @RobKennedy: My help (both via the built in help handling in VB6 and the `HtmlHelpA` function) are in process. Only when launched from Explorer do they use their own hh.exe host.